# EWS Soap Request how to search for contact based on name and email only

Tags: soap, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have a soap request like this, based on microsoft website

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://someurl"
               xmlns:xsd="http://someurl"
               xmlns:m="http://someurl"
               xmlns:soap="http://someurl"
               xmlns:t="someurl">
<soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010_SP2" />
  </soap:Header>  
<soap:Body>

  <m:ResolveNames ReturnFullContactData="true" ContactDataShape="AllProperties">
      <m:UnresolvedEntry>hart</m:UnresolvedEntry>
    </m:ResolveNames>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

as it is, it will returned a lot of stuff, because it will search "hart" on everywhere such as city, email, name, etc.

How can I specify so it search scope only on email or name only.

the soap request example is based on this link

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj190905%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx

"If you don't know the email address of the user for whom you are getting a photo, you can use the ResolveNames operation to get candidates for a possible match. If you specify "AllProperties" for the ContactDataShape attribute of the ResolveNames element, a lot of data, including user photos, will be returned for each candidate. The following example shows the XML request to resolve the name "Sadie" and return all the properties for each candidate."
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the fields searched, you should look at using the [FindItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/aa566107(v=exchg.150).aspx) operation rather than `ResolveNames`.